# Can you create a record in Aura Silently?

Tags: aura, create-records, global-actions

I use an aura component as a Global Action, linking to an external website.

I would like to track clicks of this action by creating a "clicktracker__c" record.

**Is it possible to create a record without alerting the user with purely aura/js?**

_

I leveraged `force:createRecord` but it displays a modal to the user. I know I can accomplish this with a server side call... but would rather avoid needing to apply a perm set to users.

**Current Code:**

***webForm.cmp***

```
<aura:component
    implements="force:lightningQuickAction"
    controller="webFormController"
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
</aura:component>
```

***webFormController.js***

```
({
doInit: function (cmp) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        entityApiName: "Click_Tracker__c",
        defaultFieldValues: {
            action__c: "ops/system request form",
            OwnerId: $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")
        }
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();

    window.open("https://https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightning record edit form to create the record, hide it from ui using the css, do not use [aura:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if)

basically, hiding it with css still keeps the element into dom.

then you programmatically submit the record like this:-

```
<div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Account" aura:id="accForm">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountNumber"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Industry"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Website" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" type="button" name="Save" label="Save" onclick="{!c.handleCreateAccount}" />
    </div>
```

and in js:-

```
({
    handleCreateAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("accForm").submit();
    }
})
```

> this won't show any message but creates the record.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you submit a form,  from <aura:handler> init call to the controller? @sanket-kumar

Comment: you can do it onload of the form instead of doing it from init handler.